# Tkinter - Expanding frame after (interactively) adding elements to it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *


DEF_CHANNELS = {'iris': (255, 0, 0), 'sclera': (0, 255, 0), 'pupil': (0, 0, 255)}


class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self, init_source, init_target, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.frame = Frame(self, height=400, width=500)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.channel_frame = Frame(self.frame, height=200, width=500, pady=16)
        self.channel_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

        self.channel_label = Label(self.channel_frame, text="Channel")
        self.channel_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.colour_label = Label(self.channel_frame, text="Colour")
        self.colour_label.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.channel_frames = []
        for channel, colour in DEF_CHANNELS.items():
            self.add_channel_frame(channel, colour)
        self.channel_button = Button(self.channel_frame, text="+", command=self.add_channel_frame)
        self.channel_button.grid(column=0, row=len(self.channel_frames) + 1)

    def add_channel_frame(self, def_channel="", def_colour=""):
        pair_frame = ChannelColourFrame(self.channel_frame, def_channel=def_channel, def_colour=def_colour, height=100, width=500, pady=2)
        pair_frame.grid(column=0, row=len(self.channel_frames) + 1, columnspan=2)
        self.channel_frames.append(pair_frame)


class ChannelColourFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, def_channel="", def_colour="", **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.channel_txt = Entry(self, width=30)
        self.channel_txt.insert(END, def_channel)
        self.channel_txt.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.colour_txt = Entry(self, width=30)
        self.colour_txt.insert(END, def_colour)
        self.colour_txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.color_picker_button = Button(self, text="\u2712")
        self.color_picker_button.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.remove_button = Button(self, text="-", command=self.remove)
        self.remove_button.grid(column=3, row=0)

    def remove(self):
        self.master.master.master.channel_frames.remove(self)
        self.destroy()

gui = GUI('', '')
gui.mainloop()
```

The idea is to have a `Frame` that starts with 3 default text `Entry` pairs, which a user can arbitrarily remove/add. For the most part it works fine, but with one big problem. The Frame (`self.channel_frame`) never expands past its initial height, which causes problems when more than the initial 3 `Entry` pairs appear on it.

How do I make the entire `Frame` fit to the `Entry` pairs every time one is removed/added?

As an additional question, `\u2712` appears as a box on my button, but it's supposed to be the black nib symbol (✒). Why isn't the symbol showing up despite being part of unicode?

Comment: As your code is currently written, I cannot run it. If I start the program, nothing happens, as none of your classes are called. Please, can you provide [a minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Edited. I was able to run it in its current form on https://repl.it/languages/tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating any new rows, so it's not going to grow. At the start, you create three channel frames, and they are put in rows 0, 1, and 2. You then add a "+" button in row 4.

When you click the "+" button, it adds a new row at `len(self.channel_frames) + 1`. Since `len(self.channel_frames)` is 3, it adds the new frame at row 4, which is on top of the "+" button. Thus, you aren't adding a new row.

If you move the "+" button out of the frame, or move it down each time you add a new row, your code works fine.

For example:

```
def add_channel_frame(self, def_channel="", def_colour=""):
    pair_frame = ChannelColourFrame(self.channel_frame, def_channel=def_channel, def_colour=def_colour, height=100, width=500, pady=2)
    pair_frame.grid(column=0, row=len(self.channel_frames) + 1, columnspan=2)
    self.channel_frames.append(pair_frame)
    self.channel_button.grid(column=0, row=len(self.channel_frames)+1)
```

> As an additional question, \u2712 appears as a box on my button, but it's supposed to be the black nib symbol (✒). Why isn't the symbol showing up despite being part of unicode?

Probably because the font you're using doesn't have that symbol. Try using a different font.